# Problem with SQL addition

Tags: sql, mysql

Please,

I'm trying to get some total value of user earned points in few distinctive counts, but everything is from same table.

SQL:

```
SELECT o.author_id, SUM(o.vote_value) AS vote_value, n.best AS best_sum, 
                (SUM(o.vote_value) + (10 * n.best)) AS total
                FROM comments o
                LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT COUNT(best) AS best, author_id
                  FROM comments
                  WHERE best = 1
                  GROUP BY author_id
                  ) n ON o.author_id = n.author_id
                GROUP BY o.author_id
                ORDER BY total DESC
                LIMIT 0, 4
```

Problem is if there is no BEST (default is 0, and best is 1) I'm getting nothing for "total" and "best_sum". I need 0 if user doesn't have "best" so that calculation can be performed right

Sorry, my bad english I think You will understood
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are filtering out the rows where best is not 1, so they aren't included in the group by. Try this:

```
SELECT o.author_id, SUM(o.vote_value) AS vote_value, n.best AS best_sum, 
            (SUM(o.vote_value) + (10 * n.best)) AS total
            FROM comments o
            JOIN (
              SELECT SUM(best) AS best, author_id
              FROM comments
              GROUP BY author_id
              ) n ON o.author_id = n.author_id
            GROUP BY o.author_id
            ORDER BY total DESC
            LIMIT 0, 4
```

Also, maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't this work, saving the subquery?

```
SELECT o.author_id, SUM(o.vote_value) AS vote_value, SUM(o.best) AS best_sum, 
            (SUM(o.vote_value) + (10 * SUM(o.best))) AS total
            FROM comments o
            GROUP BY o.author_id
            ORDER BY total DESC
            LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: Yap... second one is working and don't need subquery :)
Thanks, You save my day :)))

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have a 0 value if **best=NULL** try COALESCE

```
count(COALESCE(best,0) AS best)
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because best is always 1 (the WHERE clause requires it). The problem comes from the LEFT JOIN producing NULLs, so if you want to use COALESCE, you'd have to do it as sergiom suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should use COALESCE(n.best, 0)

COALESCE returns the second parameters when the first one is NULL

```
SELECT o.author_id, SUM(o.vote_value) AS vote_value, 
            COALESCE(n.best, 0) AS best_sum, 
            (SUM(o.vote_value) + (10 * COALESCE(n.best, 0))) AS total
            FROM comments o
            LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT COUNT(best) AS best, author_id
              FROM comments
              WHERE best = 1
              GROUP BY author_id
              ) n ON o.author_id = n.author_id
            GROUP BY o.author_id
            ORDER BY total DESC
            LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: I think you only fixed best_sum. Total needs the same treatment.